# Openseadragon - tileSource - url: / can i put my local image or normal jpg url?

Tags: url, openseadragon

i found this codepen. 
https://codepen.io/webconstructor/pen/oMyYBz

I want to use my image which is in local.
Is it possible that i use it?
and why can't i use another image from in any internet site ?

for example, it is working,

```
var viewer = OpenSeadragon({

      id: "openseadragon1",
      tileSources:{
          url: "https://picsum.photos/2200/2300/?image=100",
          type: 'image',
          crossOriginPolicy: 'Anonymous',
          ajaxWithCredentials: false
      },
```

but it is not working with this jpg.

url: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/07/22/20/29/life-2529859_960_720.jpg",

so could somebody explain about this, why i can not.
if i can, how ?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `crossOriginPolicy`. Sometimes you need it, but sometimes you need it to not be there.

In the case of Pixabay, they don't allow linking directly, so you won't be able to get it to work at all (but if you remove the cross origin policy you'll at least see their "Don't Link Directly" image). Here's an image from a different service you can link directly to:

https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549284936-c550b7b959ff?w=900

Local images should work just fine. Again you might need to remove the `crossOriginPolicy`.